# Test if ActionMethod exists in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have about a dozen different mail forms as part of a complex Asp.Net MVC-3 web site.

Each form has significantly different processing logic, so each form has a different ActionMethod within my FormsController.

Each form can be accessed by a URL defined in one route-mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Forms",
    "forms/{action}",
    new { controller = "Forms", action = "Index" }
);
```

I am holding a list of the action-names in a List, which is set up for DRY purposes (to populate a nav of the forms, etc). I will need to update this set of forms frequently, and I may want to refactor the form-names as they appear in the URLs (and therefore as they are defined as Action Names). I want to test that list corresponds to names of defined action-methods

It's easy to test if each form URL getting caught by the correct route-mapping. I am using NUnit with Moq:

```
MockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)
     .Returns("~/Forms/" + formUrlName);
var routeData = Routes.GetRouteData(MockHttpContext.Object);

Assert.AreEqual("Forms", routeData.Values["Controller"].ToString());            
Assert.AreEqual(formUrlName, routeData.Values["Action"].ToString());
```

But this does not guarantee that the named action-methods are themselves defined in the Froms controller.

Note also: to allow dashes in my form urls and still map to action-method names, I am defining action-names with a filter, e.g.:

```
[ActionName("blog-subscription-request")]
public ActionResult BlogSubscriptionRequest() {...
```

So...

**QUESTION:** How can I test if each item in my list of action-method names corresponds to an actual ActionMethod that exists within my FormsController?**

Answer (score 1):

I have used [MvcContrib's TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) project with success. It allows you to define a route and ensure that it maps to a specific Controller and Action like so:

```
[Test]
public void homeIndex()
{
    "~/forms/blog-subscription-request".ShouldMapTo<FormsController>(x => x.BlogRequest());
}
```

This might not be the perfect solution to your problem, but could be a decent start if you don't have too many actions.

Comment: That looks helpful: The references to the controller and method are typed, instead of strings, so the test won't compile if the types don't exist (+1). I'll give it a try...

Comment: Yeah, good that they're typed and if renamed will cascade throughout the project, but bad because you can't use TestCase or TestCastSource to run many tests at a time.